# Pass mutiple subids thru a single landing page with php?

Tags: php

I'm wanting to pass the `$cid` & `$target` parameters to the `offer[1]`, `offer[2]`, & `offer[3]` urls. I'm successfully passing the `$keyword` with no difficulty. How would I pass multiple parametera to those offer urls?

I'm grabbing them from the previous page url but I don't know how to format the code to add them in there. I was thinking

```
$offer[1] = 'http://wealthylifechoices.com/LP1?t202id=211&t202kw='.$keyword.'&c1='.$cid.'&c2='.$target;
```

But this does not work.

```
<?

//grab t202 keyword
$keyword = $_GET['t202kw'];
$cid = $GET['c1'];
$target = $GET['c2'];

//if a yahoo keyword exists, over-write the t202 keyword
//for Yahoo OVKEY = the bidded keyword, OVRAW = actual keyword
//you can change $_GET['OVRAW'] to $_GET['OVKEY'] if you would
//like to display the bidded keyword, instead of the actual keyword.
if ($_GET['OVKEY']) { $keyword = $_GET['OVKEY']; }  

//now anywhere we call echo $keyword, it will display the dynamic kw!

//extra goodie, uncomment the line below if you would like to capitalize 
//the first character in each word
//$keyword = ucwords(strtolower($keyword)); 

//Tracking202 Offer Rotation Script

//enter your affiliate urls below, you can enter as many as you want, please
//make sure that you have the affiliate url with the SUBID syntax at the end
//of it, for reference goto: subids.com for more information.
$offer[1] = 'http://wealthylifechoices.com/LP1?t202id=211&t202kw='.$keyword;
$offer[2] = 'http://wealthylifechoices.com/LP2?t202id=625&t202kw='.$keyword;
$offer[3] = 'http://wealthylifechoices.com/LP3?t202id=232&t202kw='.$keyword;

//this is the text file, which will be stored in the same directory as this file, 
//count.txt needs to be CHMOD to 777, full privlledges, to read and write to it.
$myFile = "count.txt";

//open the txt file
$fh = @fopen($myFile, 'r');
$offerNumber = @fread($fh, 5);
@fclose($fh);

//see which landing page is next in line to be shown.
if ($offerNumber >= count($offer)) {
    $offerNumber = 1;
} else {
    $offerNumber = $offerNumber + 1;
}

//write to the txt file.
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $offerNumber . "\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

//grab the subid that t202 adds
$subid = $_GET['subid'];

//redirect to the affilate url, + add the subid at the end
header('location: ' .$offer[$offerNumber] . $subid); 

?>
```

Comment: your $offer[1]  in the opening paragraph should be valid, whats the problem with it?

Comment: I can only pass the keyword to the url. I need to pass two more parameters. I'm not sure how to format the php code.

Comment: what happens? - it looks valid

Comment: $offer[1] = 'http://wealthylifechoices.com/LP1?t202id=211&t202kw=&c1=&c2='.$keyword,$cid,$target; this is wrong but i need these parameter to go into the c1 and c2 spots in the url

Comment: it is valid but i need to pass more than just the $keyword to end of the url. How do i do that?

Comment: you adding cid and target `$offer[1] = 'http://wealthylifechoices.com/LP1?t202id=211&t202kw='.$keyword '&c1='.$cid '&c2='.$target;`

Comment: I tried that and it doesnt pass the parameters. It throws an error :/

Comment: Thanks anyway bro! I'm decent with php. C# is my most fluent